# XB60 involves a lot on XSL. Could anyone share the link for advance XSL tutorials other than w3schools?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, middleware, ibm-datapower

XB60 involves a lot on XSL. Could anyone share the link for advance XSL tutorials other than w3schools ? LInks for XB60 Tutorials will also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still on the lookout

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.wdatapower/wdatapower/1.0/xb62.html

As you will notice, videos for a host of other IBM products are also available in that linkk

Make sure you bookmark the developerworks forum for all your Q&A's pertaining to DataPower based solutions

http://ibm.sitecelerate.com/developerworks/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1198

Answer (score 0):

**"Advanced XSL tutorials" are result of hard work and typically aren't available for free on the Internet.**

I would strongly recommend reading a good XSLT/XPath book or any other of the resources described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/341589/36305